# Registry Shell Extension - Mixing DLL stringtables with text

Tags: windows, shell, registry

I have a following registry keys (without icons here):

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\abc]
"MuiVERB"="Press @windows.ui.xaml.dll,-5402"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\def]
"MuiVERB"="@windows.ui.xaml.dll,-5402"
```

### How can I mix values in the DLL stringtable with text?

My target is to have `Press F4` as an `MuiVERB` value.

I've also tried replacing the `@` to `&`, doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: You can't mix. Put the whole string in your string table. (And put it in *your* string table. Don't try to steal strings from somebody else's string table. Someday they will change their table and your strings will be messed up.)